# Application of Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}, \emptyset$ be a simply connected domain and $a \in \Omega.$ Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{D}$ be a conformal map such that $f(a)=0, f'(a)>0.$ Could anyone advise me how to prove $r=\text{min}_{z \in b\Omega}|z-a|\leq \dfrac{1}{f'(a)} \leq \text{max}_{z\in b\Omega}|z-a|=R \  ?$

Here is my attempt:

Define $\psi:\mathbb{D} \to \Omega, $ by $\psi(z)=a+rz.$

$\implies \psi(z) \in D(a,r) \subset \Omega \implies |(f \circ \psi)^{\prime}(0)| \leq 1,$ by Schwarz lemma 
$\implies |f'(a)||\psi^{\prime}(0)| \leq 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

If $\phi \colon B(a, r) \to B(a', r')$ holomorphic such that 
$\phi(a) = a'$ then $|\phi'(a)| \le \frac{r'}{r}$ ( a simple consequence of Schwartz' lemma).

Apply this to $f \colon B(a,r) \to B(0,1)$ and to $f^{-1} \colon B(0,1) \to B(a, R)$.

Comment: Thank you, how do I relate this to $f'(a) \ ?$

Comment: @Alexy Vincenzo: $|f'(a)| \le \frac{1}{r}$ and $|(f^{-1})'(0)| \le \frac{R}{1}$, that is $\frac{1}{|f'(a)|} \le \frac{R}{1}$

Comment: How $|(f^{-1}) '(0)| \leq \dfrac{R}{1} \implies \dfrac{1}{|f^{\prime}(a)|} \leq R \ ?$

Comment: $a=0 \ ???????$

Comment: @Alexy Vincenzo: There is a formula for the derivative of the inverse of a function.

Comment: The formula states that $|f'(x)||(f^{-1})^{\prime}(x)|=1.$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation   $f(a)=0$ EOT