# Given Riemann mapping $f:\Omega\to\mathbb D$, prove $\inf_{z\in\partial\Omega}|z-a|\le\frac1{f'(a)}\le\sup_{z\in\partial\Omega}|z-a|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I'm looking at the following problem from some old qualifying exam I found:

> Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected proper open subset of $\Bbb C$, let $a\in\Omega$ and suppose we are given an analytic bijection $f:\Omega\to\mathbb D:=\{z:|z|<1\}$ satisfying $f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)>0$. Prove $$\inf_{z\in\partial\Omega}|z-a|\le\frac1{f'(a)}\le\sup_{z\in\partial\Omega}|z-a|.$$

To be honest, I have no idea where to start with this; my first thought was noticing that $1/f'(a)=(f^{-1})'(0)$, and was hoping to use this to try to apply the maximum modulus principle to some function involving $f'$ or $(f^{-1})'$ and $z-a$, but the first issue I come to before even trying to write a function down was realizing that $f'$ and $(f^{-1})'$ might not even be defined on the respective boundaries, so it doesn't seem like I could use maximum modulus to determine anything about the points on the boundary with respect to those functions.

I also assumed when I saw this that this was just something proved and used in the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem, but it doesn't actually seem to show up there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application of Riemann mapping theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987084/application-of-riemann-mapping-theorem) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cinf_%7Bz%5Cin%5Cpartial%5COmega%7D%7Cz-a%7C%5Cle%5Cfrac1%7Bf%27(a)%7D%5Cle%5Csup_%7Bz%5Cin%5Cpartial%5COmega%7D%7Cz-a%7C%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m=\inf_{z\in\partial\Omega} |z-a|$ and $M=\sup_{z\in\partial\Omega} |z-a|$.

Let $h_1(z)=f(mz+a)$ for $|z|<1$. It's easy to see that $h_1$ is well-defined($mz+a\in \Omega$) and $|h_1(z)|<1$ for all $|z|<1$ and $h_1(0)=f(a)=0$. Schwarz’s lemma implies that $|h_1’(0)|\leq 1$, which is exactly the left part of the desired inequality.

For the right part, consider 
$$h_2(z)=\frac{g(z)-a}{M},\ \ |z|<1,$$
where $g=f^{-1}$.